# Count elements in list for which a function returns true

Tags: function, sml

So I'm currently studying for an exam and I've been trying to solve this exercise but I really can't figure out how.

I need to implement a function that takes an 'a list and an 'a -> bool function as parameters and returns the number of 'a elements of the list that returns true when given to the 'a -> bool function taken as parameter.

So far this is the code I tried:

```
 test([],funct) = []
  |test(x::xs,funct) = if (funct(x) then 1 + test(xs,funct)
                       else 0 + (xs,funct);
```

error: Type of clause does not match the type of previous classes;
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- In the case of the empty list you return a list, not a number.
- In the other case, the `else` part is missing the recursive call to `test`.

Comment: Beside, I would avoid `0 +` in your else statement.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara, personally, I would write `(if ... then 1 else 0) + ...` and avoid duplicating the call.

Answer (score 3):

If you solve this with folding,

```
fun countp p xs = List.foldl (fn (x, c) => if p x then c+1 else c) 0 xs
```

the function will also be [tail-recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion).